# nextSelector not updating in infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I have 2 tabs on my page, each having [infinite-scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) for different content.
When the tab is switched a function is called like this :

```
function callInfScroll(newlink){
var $container = '#main';
$('#page-nav').find('a').attr('href',newlink);
$container.load(newlink, function(){
  $container.infinitescroll({
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: "This is it"
    },

    navSelector  : '#page-nav',
           // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#page-nav a',
                   // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.item',
                   // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    errorCallback: function(){
        $('#page-nav').html("Congratulations! You have reached the end of internet.");
        $('#page-nav').css({display: 'block'});
    }
  });

});
}
```

The problem is that even though the value of `#page-nav a` is changing, the change is not reflecting in infinite-scroll and its still taking the old value from the first tab.

Edit : 
My HTML :

```
    <div id="main-container" class="span8">
        <div id="main">
        </div>
        <div id="page-nav">
            <a href=""></a>
        </div>    

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a long time since u had this issue. But I crossed this very same problem today, and it took a while to get pass by it. But I finally did.

The plugin stores the path and current page inside some variable... So it doesn't really matter if you change the page_nav href.

So you need not only change the url, but also change the variables stored by the plugin.

First of all, you need to understand that the Infinite Scroll splits your URL into two pieces, the URL and the NEXT PAGE NUMBER.

Consider this as being your page_nav.

```
<div id="page_nav" style="display: none;">
    <a href="http://localhost/trunx/blog/page/all/4">Próxima Página »</a>
</div>
```

In this case, the plugin stores my URL into the **opts.path[0]**

```
http://localhost/trunx/blog/page/all/
```

And stores the current page into the **opts.state.currPage**

Let's say your new URL is like:

```
http://localhost/trunx/blog/page/programing/1
```

You can see that in this new URL I changed the category from **all** to **programing** and the page from **4** to **1**

What I did was:

```
var newPath = 'http://localhost/trunx/blog/page/programing/';
var newPage = 1;

// Changes the page_nav href.
$('#page_nav a').attr('href', newPath+newPage);

// Changes the plugin's stored variables
$('.postsBlog').infinitescroll({path:[newPath,''],state: {currPage:newPage-1}});

// This resets the pagination binder so if you had reached the end,it will now start paginating again.
$('.postsBlog').infinitescroll('bind');
```

Consider that **.postsBlog** is the container where my infiniteScroll is applied.

You can see that when I set the new currPage, I subtract 1 from it. That's because Infinity Scroll will automatically sum 1 when setting the next page.

Comment: There is a `path` setting now, where you are able to define your own logic for building the url of the next page.
This will run each time, and take the value you returned there.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442592/infinite-scroll-always-pull-nextselector-url

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without the page to experiment with, but...

Unless you remove the content from the first tab, it looks you're going to end up with multiple elements on the page with the same id ("`#page-nav`"), which is illegal in CSS.  You're probably finding that jQuery is just returning the first one.  You might consider using a class-based solution instead of ids.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the content. There's just one `page-nav` on the page, whose href i am editing..

Comment: Are you sure that the load() call is actually getting called again?  It looks like it may only run once ( on page load ).

Comment: Yes, the load gets called. The whole function `callInfScroll` gets called everytime a button on the tab is clicked. I suspect there's something fishy about the scroll plugin.